# ExtJS4 grid: reset column order button

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, extjs4

I'm working with a grid with several columns of data. I want the user to be able to move the columns around (by setting the enableColumnMove property to true on the grid) but I also need to be able to reset the column order to what I initiate the grid with.

There is no method to change a column's dataIndex property after it has been created. Is there a different way to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grid.reconfigure(null, grid.initialConfig.columns)` to reset the grid back to its original state. The first parameter is for setting a new store on the grid, but if you leave it null/undefined then the grid store will be unaffected.

Be aware that the reconfigure method may have unintended side-effects with locked grids and grids with nested column headers. But for most grids, it should work fine.

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering my questions. I tired your strategy and it didn't work, I'm probably  missing something. Are you supposed to define the initialConfig or is it automatically defined? I can call this through a reference in a controller right?

Comment: The initialConfig property should be automatically defined when you create the grid through Ext.create. If you have a reference to the grid, you can access it. What happens when you call reconfigure?

Comment: Nothing seems to happen when I call it. I only use Ext.create to create the viewport which contains my panel which contains my grid. I added the grid to my panel in the panel's initComponent: function() with the code: initComponent: function(){
                this.items = [{
                        xtype: 'grid'
                }];
                this.callParent(arguments);
        }

Comment: That will still call some variation of Ext.create behind the scenes. When you create a grid, you need to have a column definition in the config object. So grid.initialConfig.columns should always exist. Have you tried inspecting your grid in a debugger to see what the object looks like?

Comment: I am having troubling figuring out firebug enough to make use of it. I think I'll just make the columns static to avoid having to reset them :/